# Change loading state, before going to a different page

Tags: url, next.js, state

I have a webpage made with Nextjs.
On this page there are several images which will take you to a different websites.
Now when we click on any card, I set the loading state to be true which will show a loading spinner, and the browser loads the link of the card.
Now When I click back it still shows that spinner which I set to true earlier.

My Code-

```
<div className={`${styles["image-container"]}`} key={index}>
     <a href={card.card_url} 
        onClick={()=>setLoading(true)}>
            <Image
                 src={card.card_image}
                 alt={card.alt_text}
                 width={150} height={150}
            />
     </a>
</div>
```

After clicking on bac button it seems like that the component is not rendered again.
This problem is only on mobile browser, on desktop it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use router component provided by next.js here is how the code would be :
first you have import useRouter

```
import {useRouter} from 'next-router'
```

then define an async function set the state before opening page and when new page request is done right before opening it set loading
to false again

```
const router= useRouter();
const clickHandler = async ()=>{
   setLoading(true);
   await router.push(card.card_url);
   setLoading(false);
};
...
<div className={`${styles["image-container"]}`} key={index}>
 <a href={card.card_url} 
    onClick={clickHandler}>
        <Image
             src={card.card_image}
             alt={card.alt_text}
             width={150} height={150}
        />
     </a>
</div>
```